# How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have 3 repositories in my settings.xml because I need artifacts from all of them. Whenever a dependency is not found, Maven tries

```
Downloading: http://some.server/mvn2repo/releases/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/...
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:pom:2.9.1' in repository
Downloading: http://some.server/mvn2repo/3rdParty/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/...
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:pom:2.9.1' in repository
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/lucene-core-2.9.1.pom
<success>
```

all repositories, but most of the time finds the artifact in central (repo1) of course. I want Maven to check this repo first. I tried order of declarations in settings.xml, but did not work. According to *fgysin* I also tried the reverse order, which didn't change anything.

My Maven version:

```
C:\>mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_15
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_15\jre
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows vista" version: "6.0" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

My `settings.xml`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>space</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>s1-releases</id>
                <name>System One Releases</name>
                <url>http://some.server/mvn2repo/releases</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>s1-3rdParty</id>
                <name>System One 3rd Party Releases</name>
                <url>http://some.server/mvn2repo/3rdParty</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>space</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Let's vote for the following issues: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4946 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4400

Comment: Just pick a working repo and `only` configure it...

Comment: @HendyIrawan appears that MNG-4400 was fixed with maven 3.0 FWIW

Comment: this is the updated link to the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065165/maven-repository-lookup-order

Comment: Updated issues links https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4946

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As far as I know, the order of the repositories in your pom.xml will also decide the order of the repository access.

As for configuring repositories in settings.xml, I've read that the order of repositories is interestingly enough the *inverse* order of how the repositories will be accessed.

Here a post where someone explains this curiosity:
http://community.jboss.org/message/576851

Comment: Your link looks promising and I tried reversing the order, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Hmm, strange. What version of Maven are you using?

Comment: Indeed, on a fresh project the order is 1) active profiles desc (reversed) AND then 2) repositories asc. So "central" should be the first repo in the last activated profile.

Comment: It is not the inverse order. You should specify the local repo to be the first one in your <repositories> tag

Answer (score 42):

None of these answers were correct in my case.. the order seems dependent on the alphabetical ordering of the <id> tag, which is an arbitrary string.  Hence this forced repo search order:

```
            <repository>
                <id>1_maven.apache.org</id>
                <releases>  <enabled>true</enabled>  </releases>
                <snapshots> <enabled>true</enabled> </snapshots>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>2_maven.oracle.com</id>
                <releases>  <enabled>true</enabled>  </releases>
                <snapshots> <enabled>false</enabled> </snapshots>
                <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
```

Comment: It must have been some specific (bugged?) range of maven versions. I have maven 3.6 and it's the order as lined out in the accepted answer.

Comment: yeah I think that bug was this one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400 after Maven 3.0 it reads in the proper order declared

Answer (score 12):

Also, consider to use a repository manager such as Nexus and configure all your repositories there.

Comment: Why you can't use it? If that's because you can't maintain your own server, you can give a try to [Artifactory Online](https://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorycloud_overview), you'll get a cloud Maven repo up and running in minutes.