# Maven repository lookup order

Tags: maven, repository, maven-3, archiva

We have an internal Apache Archiva based repository and we have configured the repositories tag in pom.xml to be as follows. Can I assume that all dependency access will get resolved by internal repository if you have access to it and will get resolved by other repositories listed below, if internal repository is down for a certain reason.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.1.2/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
....
</repositories>
```

EDIT:

I want to do away with the .m2/settings.xml file. I want to define this in my pom.xml file, so that if my repository manager is UP and running I would want the runtime to connect there, else would want to fallback into the other repositories. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 5):

Maven 3.0 had it fixed as you can see in Maven developer's Jira below. The lookup will be done **in the order they are declared**.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400

Comment: For anyone interested, the JIRA ticket MNG-4400 moved to [issues.apache.org](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400).