# How mvn is workings if you have server repository?

Tags: maven

I jave settinngs.xml with 3 repositories 
when I 
rum `mvn clean install` 
from where does `mvn` like the dependencies 
does it look from the repositories ( buil1,buil2,buil3) or from public nexus ? what is the order of nexus ?

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>build</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>build1</id>
          <url>url1....</url>
        </repository>
           <repository>
          <id>build2</id>
          <url>url2....</url>
        </repository>
                <repository>
          <id>build3</id>
          <url>url3....</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>build</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: First you should start using a repository manager where you define those repositories furthermore you define the order of visiting. Apart from that you can define rules to pick up particular groupId's from one repo and other groupId from another repo...Apart from that if you don't define a mirrorOf the order is going through the defined repos by given order and finally if not found going into maven central...

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml)

and

[Maven repository lookup order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065165/maven-repository-lookup-order)

After [Maven Bug (MNG-4400)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400) was fixed, artifacts are resolved in defined repository order.

Comment: Can I determine that the public nexus will be the first one ?

Comment: sure you can. think about it - it does not really matter, as long as we can assume there are no 2 different versions for the same artifact. meaning, JAR-A with version 4 will be the same one among all repo's. so maven will try the 1st repo, if it does not find this artifact it keeps searching for the next repo etc....

Comment: how I can determine that the public nexus will be first as in my example ? I didn't define the public nexus as repo but part as the schema location?

Comment: just a hint that mentioned Bug is more than 8 years old..if someone is using Maven before 3.X sorry..

Comment: @user1365697 You have define a nexus repo as schema location? Sorry that does not make sense ? Do i misunderstand a thing?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not expert in mvn what is the meaning that the repo us define as scheme location? My goal is to define 4 repo public nexus and more 3

Comment: As I mentioned do the whole configuration of different repositories in Nexus and use the default setup for the settings.xml (read the docs on Nexus for that)...