# How to define in the maven pom.xml, which dependency should be downloaded from which repository?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

In the `pom.xml` I can define `repositories` and `dependencies`, but I do not see a way to declare which dependencies should be taken from which repository. For example, dependency A should be loaded from repository X and dependency B - from repository Y, with a different URL. How do I declare this in my pom.xml and/or settings.xml?

Comment: Maven 3 lookups for dependencies in the order that repositories are declared. It will use the first available.

Comment: Short answer to this: It's not possible. Furthermore repositories should not being defined in your pom file...use settings.xml for that or even better use a repository manager...there you can defined such rules..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

But you do not need to care.

Maven goes through all the declared repositories to look for the dependencies. So it will eventually find them.

Answer (score 0):

Maven 3 lookups for dependencies in the order that repositories are declared. It will use the first available.
[Maven repository lookup order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065165/maven-repository-lookup-order)