# download dependecy only form a specific repository with maven

Tags: maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml)

I'm using an internal maven repository for a project, and when I specify a dependency I'd like that maven looks this dependency only in the internal repository and not in the public repositories.
Example:

```xml
<repositories>
 ...
 <myrepository...>
 <publicrepo...>
</repositories>

[..]


<dependency>
        <groupId>imygroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If I build the maven project I can see that maven try to download the artifact `myartifactId` from all public repository I specified in the pom.
Is there a way to specify that all artifacts with `groupId` should be find in the internal repository and not in the other?

This will solve some performance problem during the build task.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is with repository managers like Nexus or Archiva

Answer (score 1):

You may find some clues here : [How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml)

The order of repositories seems to be inverse order of declaration in settings.xml