# For a specific dependency artifact, how does Maven 3 specify where to download it from?

Tags: maven, maven-3

There seems to be surprisingly little "definitive" information on the subject. The closest [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xmlhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml) question eventually leads to [a thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/576851?_sscc=t) that provides some partial information, but it's incomplete. The [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGSITE-124) referenced in the thread has not been updated in 3 years, so I assume nothing has changed from that time.

Here's the question:

**Once Maven needs a specific dependency artifact, taking into account:**

- **repository definitions,**
- **mirrors**

**defined in:**

- **the current POM,**
- **the parent POMs,**
- **settings.xml**
- **active profiles derived from the above,**

**how does Maven 3.x determine which repository to download from?**

Note that this question does **not** concern resolving a dependency's version.

Comment: The order is as far as i know: Maven system settings (which is part of the maven distribution itself). User settings.xml and than pom file. And may be some activated profiles depending where they are defined.

Comment: @khmarbaise : this is consistent with the link I referenced, but only paints part of the picture.