# Maven multiple repositories -- how exactly does maven decide which repo to fetch which artifact?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a project that needs to fetch artifacts from two different repos. And even the artifacts inside the repos have dependencies to one another. For example, my project might depend on artifact A (in repo 1), which depends on artifact B( in repo 2), which again depends on artifact C (in repo 1 again).

I am having a lot of trouble configuring my settings.xml to make it work (For example mvn always tries to go to repo 1 for artifact B, which is wrong). Anybody got a clue how exaclty this is decided in maven?

Comment: I think your answer should be somewhere here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html ?

Comment: How do you have configured your settings.xml ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Whatever I have done is definitely wrong. I am curious in general how does maven solve the multiple repository problem

Comment: I don't think you can control that. Maven will search in the repositories in the order that you define them in the settings.xml, until it finds what it needs.

Comment: But it doesn't!  It looks in repo 1, doesn't find it, and then gives up, and never even attempts looking at repo 2 as far as I can tell.  What gives?

Comment: And things are clearly more complicated than "just look in settings.xml" or else there wouldn't be people writing blog posts like this one: https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: There already appears to be an accepted answer which describe repository ordering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml

Answer (score 4):

All repositories are searched in order.

The number one reason why this does not happen are `<mirror>`s. Mirrors override repository definitions. If you, for example, define a mirror with `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` it will take *all* the requests and your other repository definitions just don't matter any more.

The number two reason is problems with one of the repositories. A repository which does not contain an artifact is expected to answer with `404`. If it instead returns some gibberish or a `500` error or anything else, this might break the resolution.

Comment: When you say "in order", what order is this?  The one in settings.xml?  Or does the pom affect things too?  (assume no mirrors)

Comment: That I don't know. One more remark: Inside companies, you usually don't put multiple repositories into a `settings.xml` but let your Nexus or Artifactory do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Well, it turns out that in my company, we have several Nexus servers, some of which manage multiple repos.  Last question: according to your explanation, it seems that if there are no games with mirrors, and no misbehaving servers, then removing repositories should never help.  At most it saves a bit of time and network traffic, but it can never make something findable if it wasn't already findable.  Right?

Comment: That would be my understand, yes. For a company my advice would be to proxy the other Nexus so that your `settings.xml` only needs one. But I understand that you probably cannot change that.

Comment: Thanks!  Then I wonder what on earth is going wrong...

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new question containing the settings.xml.

Comment: Doubt that I'm allowed to post that thing online.

Comment: Then you might construct a comparable dummy version.

Comment: I just tried turning on more verbose logging, and it appears that you might be right after all.  It looks like they all are getting tried after all.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay things are finally making much more sense.  There are some artifacts that are in both repos, but the pom files don't match!   So I end up with a totally different dependency tree depending on which pom I pick up.  Arrrggg!