# How do I prevent maven from checking a remote repository for certain artifacts?

Tags: maven

In order to include a specific maven dependency, I included its repository in my pom. Because of this, maven will check every repository for every artifact. This repository is rather slow so I would rather have maven only reach out to it when checking for the dependencies that it provides.

Is there a way to limit maven to check a repository for certain artifacts? Perhaps certain group IDs?

Comment: I recommend to use a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva which will solve this problem. And no there is no such configuration to control that.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can impose such filters, but Maven asks the repositories in a certain order until it finds the artifact. As we handle this problem through Nexus, I am not experienced in this, but the question [How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5325407/927493) gives (maybe outdated) information about this.