# what is the order of repositories in settings.xml maven looks for while resolving dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependency-management

We use settings.xml where we have several repositories and pluginrepositories defined which also include our own enterprise artifactory.The pom.xml doesn't use any repositories and its all through settings.xml Since the builds run on ephemeral jenkins agent so everytime its a new fetch of dependencies as there is no cache.
Today i saw a serious outage with
https://repository.mulesoft.org
so several of the repos under this domain like https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/ and
http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/
were down for a while
Unfortunately maven always reached out to these repos and when it got a bad gateway it would fail the build and not even attempt to reach out to enterprise artifactory repositories that are also defined in the settings.xml
I am wondering what is the order that maven looks at when it reaches out to the defined repositories in settings.xml to resolve dependencies. I saw an interesting post at
[How to set order of repositories in Maven settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325407/how-to-set-order-of-repositories-in-maven-settings-xml)
and it looks to me its the albhabetical order of the repository/pluginRepository id that matters here.
However want to confirm if anyone knows about this?

Comment: Define all those repositories in your Artifactory...instead of settings.xml...

Comment: Yeah that is a possible solution, but i am still curious as to what is the order in which maven looks for repositories defined in settings.xml while resolving dependencies?